# How to view AndroidManifest.xml from APK file?

Tags: android, xml, apk, android-manifest, aapt

Is it possible to view `Androidmanifest.xml` file?

I just changed the extension of the `apk` file to `zip`. This `zip` file contains the `Androidmanifest.xml` file. But I am unable view the contents of `Androidmanifest.xml`. It is fully encrypted.

How can I view the `Androidmanifest.xml` file?

Comment: I have one APK file. I need to view the Androidmanifest.xml file. because i used one framework. That APK file also used same framework. So i need to see how to configure the Androidmanifest file from that APK file.

Comment: I wasn't able to do this in chrome, but when I opened it in Firefox and chose to *view the source code* (otherwise there's just error) then I was able to *partially* see the content.

Answer (score 250, accepted):

Yes you can view XML files of an Android APK file. There is a tool for this: [`android-apktool`](https://apktool.org/)

> It is a tool for reverse engineering 3rd
> party, closed, binary Android apps

How to install apktool: [see instructions on the apktool website](https://apktool.org/docs/install)

Now copy the `APK` file also in that directory and run the following command in your command prompt:

```
apktool d HelloWorld.apk -o ./HelloWorld
```

This will create a directory "`HelloWorld`" in your current directory. Inside it you can find the `AndroidManifest.xml` file in decrypted format, and you can also find other `XML` files inside the `"HelloWorld/res/layout"` directory.

Here `HelloWorld.apk` is your Android APK file.

See the below screen shot for more information:
[image]

Comment: This is nice, but I'd like to know how to just look at the AndroidManifest.xml without having to download all of this. Is it encrypted or compressed?

Comment: **@JohnnyLambada**: Yes you can open and view it in a archiving tool like: **WinRar/WinZip/7Zip** but it make no sense because it is in encrypted form.

Comment: is it possible to decrypt , change it a bit (for example the minSdkVersion) , and then put it back into the apk ?

Comment: The apktool is deprecated. Better refer to their [project homepage](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) for latest version.

Comment: I get:
Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: Multiple resources:
        at brut.androlib.res.data.ResConfig.addResource(Unknown Source)

Comment: @VikasPatidar This is great.. but can you please tell how to do this on the device. I mean with SDK (using XMLPullParse/Sax/DocumentBuilder).

Comment: @Kishore: You can not directly read `AndroidManifest.xml` from your application. However you can access various information like Version name, Version Code, Package Name etc. using the official API's.

Comment: is it possible to use the apkTool even within an Android app?

Comment: is it possible to Look see Decrepted mean normal words i want to see Manifesto file or .xml Designing files is any way to do ....?? i got all the things by APK to convert in zip and Decampile code by tool Decompiler i can get xml or .manifesto details so how do i can look these file .code in Decreption format .....????

Comment: Command seems different in latest version, need to use "-o" before destination folder. Didn't worked for me, either way.

Comment: @JohnnyLambada You can try this http://www.javadecompilers.com/ or this http://www.decompileandroid.com/.

Comment: @VikasPatidar, as far as i know the android manifest is not encrypted, it is only in binary form .

Comment: @turkishweb thanks for the correction, I will update it. it has been so long since I answered it.

Comment: Now that [Google released the ClassyShark Android binary inspection tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191762/how-to-view-androidmanifest-xml-from-apk-file/40686067#40686067), this answer is obsolete.

Comment: Now command has changed for the latest version `apktool d your_destination youraApk.apk`

Comment: downvoting because it is an old answer. the easiest approach is to use Android Studio as indicated by @jonas

Comment: Also downvoting, no longer works. I get an error ... Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: Could not decode arsc file

Comment: I've used the @Deqing's comment to download the apk tool from [here](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) and then execute the following command in the terminal (_Windows 10_) `>java -jar apktool_2.6.0.jar d com.mihkov.helloworldapp.apk`.

Comment: This answer is obsolete. The answer by @jonas-jongejan should be accepted instead.

Comment: @JohnnyLambada, you may consider unzip AndroidManifest.xml only, then zip it to a new apk to be decrypted by apktool.

Answer (score 237):

Android Studio can now show this. Go to `Build` > `Analyze APK...` and select your apk. Then you can see the content of the AndroidManifest file.

Comment: This feature has been added recently and I would also like to suggest this unless you are keen using the command line and you have the platform-tools in your path set up.

Comment: this should be upvoted to become the best answer, other methods are now unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: There is a command-line version of this built-in as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54874783/89818

Comment: Nothing happens.

Comment: I can open the APK like that but the Manifest is a binary file full on NULL

Answer (score 71):

Google has just released a cross-platform open source tool for inspecting APKs (among many other binary Android formats):

> [ClassyShark](https://github.com/google/android-classyshark) is a standalone binary inspection tool for Android developers. It can reliably browse any Android executable and show important info such as class interfaces and members, dex counts and dependencies. ClassyShark supports multiple formats including libraries (.dex, .aar, .so), executables (.apk, .jar, .class) and all Android binary XMLs: AndroidManifest, resources, layouts etc.

[image: ClassyShark screenshot]

Install version 8.2:

```bash
wget https://github.com/google/android-classyshark/releases/download/8.2/ClassyShark.jar
```

Run:

```bash
java -jar ClassyShark.jar -open <file.apk>
```

Comment: This is 10000 times easier than Apktool!

Comment: is it editable?

Answer (score 67):

`aapt d xmltree com.package.apk AndroidManifest.xml`

will dump the `AndroidManifest.xml` from the specified APK. It's not in XML form, but you can still read it.

[`aapt`](http://elinux.org/Android_aapt) (Android Asset Packaging Tool) is a built in tool that comes with the Android SDK.

Comment: (for aapt2) aapt2.exe d xmltree package.apk --file AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 47):

In this [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/082c3c364ca56c25), Dianne Hackborn tells us we can get info out of the AndroidManifest using aapt.

I whipped up this quick unix command to grab the version info:

```bash
aapt dump badging my.apk | sed -n "s/.*versionName='\([^']*\).*/\1/p"
```

Answer (score 45):

You can use [`apkanalyzer`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apkanalyzer.html), the command-line version of the [APK Analyzer](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer.html) bundled with the Android SDK. Just execute the following command on the CLI:

```
/path/to/android-sdk/tools/bin/apkanalyzer manifest print /path/to/app.apk
```

You only have to replace `/path/to/android-sdk` with the correct path to your version of the Android SDK, and `/path/to/app.apk` with the path to your APK file.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it does not require to install anything from unverified sources.

Comment: note that this doesn't seem to work on Windows :( https://stackoverflow.com/a/54593118/997940

Comment: I get error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The tools directory property is not set, please make sure you are executing apkanalyzer, I didn't know how to solve it

Comment: This is most likely the path you need if you’re on macOS: `~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/apkanalyzer manifest print <apk>`

Comment: works on windows now. the version I used was downloaded in 2022.

Answer (score 22):

You can use this command: **save to file** `AndroidManifest.txt`

```
aapt dump xmltree gmail.apk AndroidManifest.xml > AndroidManifest.txt
```

Comment: `d` is an abbreviation for `dump`, which makes this answer identical to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191762/how-to-view-androidmanifest-xml-from-apk-file/28464940#28464940), which was posted more than a year earlier.

Comment: Yes, but this code save in file `> AndroidManifest.txt`.

Comment: lol, that's the same answer, dumping the file is not making the difference

Comment: It's a better written answer: I skipped the other one because I thought the output would be binary, but here it is clear right away that AndroidManifest.txt will be ASCII readable by humans.

Answer (score 18):

Aapt2, included in the Android SDK build tools can do this - no third party tools needed.

```bash
$(ANDROID_SDK)/build-tools/28.0.3/aapt2 d --file AndroidManifest.xml app-foo-release.apk
```

Starting with build-tools v29 you have to add the command `xmltree`:

```bash
$(ANDROID_SDK)/build-tools/29.0.3/aapt2 d xmltree --file AndroidManifest.xml app-foo-release.apk
```

Comment: This doesn't output the original XML, but it's neat if I just need to look at a value in there without having to extract the APK or write to a temporary file.

Comment: This very weirdly required both XML and .apk, I only had the XML, I found out that Archive Manager can "zipped" it to ".apk" and I just provided that as the `.apk` and then it worked :-)

Answer (score 16):

To decode the `AndroidManifest.xml` file using [axmldec](https://github.com/ytsutano/axmldec):

```
axmldec -o output.xml AndroidManifest.xml
```

or

```
axmldec -o output.xml AndroidApp.apk
```

Comment: This works and can be easily installed via Homebrew: `brew tap ytsutano/toolbox` `brew install axmldec`

Comment: not recognized under windows...

Comment: works on windows, thx

Answer (score 8):

The **AXMLParser** and **APKParser.jar** can also do the job, you can see the link. [AXMLParser](http://code.google.com/p/xml-apk-parser)

Comment: That tool hasn't been updated in give years. Google has just released an [Android binary inspection tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191762/how-to-view-androidmanifest-xml-from-apk-file/40686067#40686067) in Nov 2016.

Answer (score 8):

There is an online tool that lets you upload an APK It decompiles it and finally lets you to download a zip with all sources, manifest XML file and so on decompiled, all of that without having to install any program on your computer:
http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk

Also if you wish just to check on some params you can, by their UI

Comment: Worked on an APK in August, didn't work on another one in Nov.

Comment: apktools did not seem to create a directory for me with the output, and aapt did not show the result in XML format. This website worked like a charm.

Comment: ezpz, DaaS "Decompiler as a Service" that's nice and worked well for me, no need to install anything

Answer (score 4):

All these answers seem a *bit* over-engineered!

1. Just grab this chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apk-downloader/fgljidimohbcmjdabiecfeikkmpbjegm
2. Download the `.apk` file you want from the playstore using the above extension.
3. Upload the `.apk` to this online tool to grab the `manifest.xml`: https://www.sisik.eu/apk-tool

Comment: I love whats behind door no 3!

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use Jadx: https://github.com/skylot/jadx

Just open your APK and in treeview select "AndroidManifest.xml".
It will be readable just like that.

Comment: and to edit it (that single file) without extracting other files?

Comment: @gumuruh In Jadx you can only view AndroidManifest.xml, other resources and code.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use my app, [App Detective](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zmarties.detective) to view the manifest file of any app you have installed on your device.

Comment: is it editable?

Comment: The app sucks (bad UI/UX) and upon opening the AndroidManifest I see a blank screen.

Answer (score 2):

Another useful (Python-based) tool for this is [Androguard](https://github.com/androguard/androguard), using its `axml` sub-command:

```sh
androguard axml my.apk -o my.xml
```

This extracts and decodes the app manifest in one go. Unlike apktool this doesn't unpack anything else.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but I thought I would mention, of your phone has root, you can view it directly on your phone using the root explorer app.  You don't even have to extract it to see.

Answer (score 0):

Just upload the apk at https://www.sisik.eu/apk-tool and you can view the AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score -1):

The file needs to be decompiled (or deodex'd not sure which one). But here's another way to do it:

```
-Download free Tickle My Android tool on XDA: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1633333https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1633333
-Unzip
-Copy APK into \_WorkArea1\_in\ folder
-Open "Tickle My Android.exe"
-Theming Menu
-Decompile Files->Any key to continue (ignore warning)
-Decompile Files->1->[Enter]->y[Enter]
-Wait for it to decompile in new window... Done when new window closes
-Decompiled/viewable files will be here: \_WorkArea3\_working\[App]\
```