# Is there a way to view the contents of a manifest file from an APK?

Tags: android, facebook, android-manifest

I saw [here](http://www.howardforums.com/showthread.php/1689618-Huawei-Ascend-sync-with-Facebook-problem) that someone listed the contents of the manifest of the official Facebook app's APK.  Is there a way to decompile that, or is that info available elsewhere?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse the AndroidManifest.xml file inside an .apk package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097813/how-to-parse-the-androidmanifest-xml-file-inside-an-apk-package)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to view AndroidManifest.xml from APK file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191762/how-to-view-androidmanifest-xml-from-apk-file)

Answer (score 3):

An `APK` file is just a `JAR` - change the extension to `.JAR`, and use a decompression tool to decompress it.

If you're using windows, you could just use `WinRAR` - that should decompress JARs.

In addition to that, a `JAR` is just a regular `ZIP` file - so you could technically just change the APK extension to `.ZIP` instead, and open it up using pretty much any decompression tool (as mentioned by Peter).

Here's some more info on `JARs`:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_file

Comment: And I just deleted my post because you were basically right. And I posted it because I had page in browser open for some time and I saw your post just after I submitted mine. Anyhow, it was a trivial question and a trivial answer (and both not really suitable for SO, but for http://android.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I like the question and answer to be here (even if trivial). This is the place for programmes - android.stackexchange.com is the site for users (as I understand).

Comment: Yeah, android.stackexchange.com is more for users - not really for developers.

Comment: I'm aware that you can easily unzip an apk. The problem is that when you open the manifest file, it is a bunch of unreadable characters. I've tried this with a few different apks. I've been using the method of changing it to a .zip and using Windows built-in decompressor. Is it possible that it would decompress differently as a jar file?