# Is it possible to edit Androidmanifest.XML After packaging the APK?

Tags: android, xml

I would like to edit the Androidmanifest.XML file after packaging the Apk for strange reasons

For more info visit this post [How to exclude devices with low RAM in Google Play Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663188/how-to-exclude-devices-with-low-ram-in-google-play-store?noredirect=1#comment29199868_19663188)

Please do explain if possible. It is an unsigned apk BTW.

Comment: @MaulikSheth Thanks for Claryifying

Comment: Of course it is possible to edit manifest, although there's certain things you CANNOT do, like changing package name, but you can definitely edit it in order to update/add activities, change versioncode, minsdkversion etc, of course all these changes should  be done with an update to your whole app in the playstore...

Comment: @MartinCazares Will it be possible to add filters? I mean to restrict screen sizes.

Comment: Definitely, but as i said, you should upload a new apk with this specs and the new devices trying to install must fill the requirements, you can also be more restrictive in the SDK version if you want...

Comment: @MartinCazares Can you explain how to add filters? What i do is make game in construct 2.Export it for android and compile it online and they mail me unsigned apk.

Answer (score 19):

Try this under Linux:

```sh
cd tmp ; wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/master/scripts/linux/apktool
wget https://bitbucket.org/iBotPeaches/apktool/downloads/apktool_2.4.0.jar
mv apktool_2.4.0.jar apktool.jar
mv apktool* /usr/local/bin
chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/apktool*
```

Then, you can decompile the APK with:

```sh
apktool d your-app.apk
```

Then, you can edit AndroidManifest.xml under the folder your-app generated by the previous command. Then, you can compile again with:

```sh
apktool b your-app
```

Then, you have to sign again you APP, you can use your own keystore (p.e generated by Android Studio), or create new one with the following procedure:

```sh
keytool -genkey -v -keystore keyStore.keystore -alias app -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore keyStore.keystore your-app/dist/your-app.apk app
```

Finally you have your APK again. You can copy it from "your-app/dist/your-app.apk" file.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 15):

You can decompile your apk with [apktool](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) and your manifest will be readable. After editing your manifest you can compile and create apk again. Remember to sign you apk after creating new apk.

[Similar question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975618/android-how-to-decode-and-decompile-any-apk-file)
[Similar question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898042/is-there-a-way-to-view-the-contents-of-a-manifest-file-from-an-apk)

Comment: APKtool is not a good solution. With complex applications it will often break the app.

Comment: @John Hi I wonder what should we use then? Thanks!

Comment: I tried this but when I open the manifest file, the characters are messy..