# Create Multiple copy of android application

Tags: java, android, user-controls

i want to create multiple copies of android application in same device. first approach  is i can make Create user account in my app and then i am able to use two accounts of whatsapp,yahoo etc applications but i fail to do this please help me how can i do this stuf...
actually i want to make an app like this app : [app Cloner](https://github.com/prife/VirtualAppDoc)

this App is actually manage two account simultaneously in android device. Please provide guideline how can i achieve this functionality..

---

And find a solution for this we have to create an virtual environment like as lody done so for this we need to implement C and Java knowledge because without the knowledge of NDK we can not create applications to manage multiple accounts. 
So we need to create virtual core inside our app that provide virtual environment for other applications.
Working Examples 
[Document Virtual app](https://github.com/prife/VirtualAppDoc)

[Best Google Example](https://github.com/asLody/VirtualApp)

Comment: Check out flavour concept http://www.androidauthority.com/building-multiple-flavors-android-app-706436/

Comment: No need to create flavor of my own application i need to create for other installed application on Phone.

Comment: @Ashish Can you close the question? In case that the solution provided fix your issue?

Comment: @AndroidStorm I have not find solution is the correct way to do

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is make sure that you change the **package name**, **applicationId** and create a variant, you can follow this link to do it.

[How to install different app variants on one Android device](https://blog.grandcentrix.net/how-to-install-different-app-variants-on-one-android-device/)

Important:
***If you want also you can read this files into the apk file.***.

And as a DevrimTuncer mentioned:

*You can decompile your apk with apktool and your manifest will be readable. After editing your manifest you can compile and create apk again. Remember to sign you apk after creating new apk.* Link to the answer [Here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664129/is-it-possible-to-edit-androidmanifest-xml-after-packaging-the-apk)