# Rename android name application with javascript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am currently working on a project using the javascript language. What I do is rename the extension of my apk to zip file. Then through the JZIP library I capture the data from the androidManifest.xml file to edit the name of the application, but this file is encrypted and I can not edit it. There is some way to be able to decode that file to native xml, apply changes and re-encode it. This is posible? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you could use `apktool`/`aapt` to decode your AndroidManifest.xml.

If you want just update AndroidManifest, put it back in the apk and run it - it won't work. The checksum and the signature won't be valid anymore.

If you thinking about decompiling the app and recompiling it with the updated manifest, it might work, but the result will depend on the complexity of the application. Keep in mind that you'll need to sign the app.

There're multiple questions similar to yours, you could try to find luck with them:

[Decompile an APK, modify it and then recompile it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370326/decompile-an-apk-modify-it-and-then-recompile-it)

[How to view AndroidManifest.xml from APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191762/how-to-view-androidmanifest-xml-from-apk-file)

[Is it possible to edit AndroidManifest.xml after packaging the APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664129/is-it-possible-to-edit-androidmanifest-xml-after-packaging-the-apk)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, then there is another way to read encode androidManifest from javascript and re-code again? Yes I need to sign apk but I will perform with external app

Comment: I doubt that it can be done in a client-side js, it looks like a server task. I would create a web service which has an access to the aapt tool and send an APK and a new app name to it for processing. Then I would download a decoded result.

Comment: Thanks men this is the accepted answer. By the way, could you give me your help in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49599747/compile-androidmanifest-xml-from-java-aapt

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. First you need apktool.jar, after make a java rest API like spring boot, and execute apktool commands with processbuilder java method. The only way that I found to change appname programatically is decompiled, edit androidManifest and smali archives and compiled again the apk with apktool or aapt