# Compile androidManifest.xml from Java (aapt)

Tags: java, android, xml, aapt

How can I use aapt from Java to compile the file `androidManifest.xml` to axml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn´t do it.. but the best solution is apktool.jar with processbuilder java method to execute commands from this jar, like windows command prompt to compile and decompile your apk. Sadly the apktool consumes a lot of RAM, you need a good server