# Google Play requires versionCode to be set to a positive 32-bit integer in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, apache-flex, intellij-idea

I am desperately trying to upload an Android-App that has been developed and packaged with Adobe Flex SDK 4.6 using Intellij IDEA. The PKCS#12 was created using openSSL (I just want to mention this, but I don't think this is the problem).

Everything worked fine until I got the silly desire to publish the App into the Google Play store. It destroyed all my dreams with this simple sentence:

```
Google Play requires versionCode to be set to a positive 32-bit integer in AndroidManifest.xml.
```

Okay, its not a secret that you can not define the Android versionCode from Flex SDK directly. You have to use the -Tag, which I did. Actually I tried this in several different combinations (of course only one at a time) like:

```
<versionNumber>0</versionNumber>
<versionNumber>1</versionNumber>
<versionNumber>2</versionNumber>
<versionNumber>0.0.1</versionNumber>
<versionNumber>1.0.0</versionNumber>
<versionNumber>2.0.1</versionNumber>
```

... and whatever you can imagine ...

But whatever I did, when I upload the APK, the status bar is going to 100% and starts counting backwards as if it was laughing at me and ends up with the above error message.

From the Adobe Community I learned that on Android, the AIR version a.b.c is translated to the Android version code using the formula: a*1000000 + b*1000 + c.

Well, using this formula all my values for the -Tag should become a 32-Bit Integer.

Any Ideas?

Comment: My app uploaded fine to the Google Play store using 1.0.1 as the versionNumber. I'm not sure what the problem may be here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Flex SDK has a bug which is listed [here](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/765086) so that I had to choose a workaround that I would like to share with you here.

My solution is to unpack the APK-File, edit the AndroidManifest.xml, pack the APK-File again and sign it. I use the apktool and jarsigner (part of JDK).

```
java -jar apktool.jar d MyApp.apk // unpack
// edit AndroidManifest.xml
java -jar apktool.jar b MyApp_patched.apk // repack
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -storetype pkcs12 -keystore ../AndroidCertificates.p12 MyApp_fixed.apk "1" // sign
```

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug in Flex, try numbers such as 999. See this thread http://forums.adobe.com/thread/765086

You can also take apart the apk that Flex generates and take a look at the manifest to see what is going on, you might even be able to put it back together after manualy cahnging the value check out [How to view AndroidManifest.xml from APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191762/how-to-view-androidmanifest-xml-from-apk-file)

Comment: Was just going to suggest patching the APK - normally a silly thing to do when you have the source, but if the tool flow is being this obstinate, at a certain point one might just want a shortcut to a fix.

Comment: I just decompiled the APK using apktool and had a look at the resulting AndroidManifest.xml. The versionCode was set to "0". This is definitely a bug.

Comment: That link is from 2010 and used a beta version of Flash Builder.  This can't be a bug in Flex; but it may be a bug with the AIR SDK shipped with the Flex SDK/Flash Builder.  I have not run into it personally and have used similar numbers to what the original poster used.

Comment: I am not using FB but Intellij IDEA which package the APK using the Flex SDK. So it is most likely a bug in the Flex SDK since the resulting versionCode is "0".

Answer (score 1):

Version code is an incremental number to keep track of which build is the latest.

What your talking about is the versionName, versionName can be 0.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT or whatever

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my.app"
    android:versionCode="23"
    android:versionName="1.2.1" >
```

versionCode is an integer

versionName is a String

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#vcode

Comment: Thank you, but I am aware of that. The Problem is that I am using the flex SDK where you can not enter the versionCode since it is beeing derived from the versionNumber (Flex SDK). Please have a look at the formula I mentioned. The result should be what the Flex SDK puts into the versionCode-value.