# Run quickmemo feature on LG android phone from activity or press both volume keys at the same time programmatically

Tags: android, events, key

I am trying to create some application which is implementing QuickMemo feature from LG (Optimus G in my case).

Can I create some listener for button to launch QuickMemo? I can run it by pressing both volume up and volume down keys at the same time, but how to do it from my activity?

Comment: When you asked LG, what did they tell you?

Comment: There no any API for this feature.I want that user will not have to press volume keys together, he has to pres only simple imagebutton on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at this application manifest file if its possible and check the activities for `android:exported` value and check its intent filters. This will tell whether you are allowed to launch it from another app.

This post might help you
[How to view AndroidManifest.xml from APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191762/how-to-view-androidmanifest-xml-from-apk-file)

> You can directly use aapt l -a name.apk command to see the
>   manifest.xml.
>
> This link might help http://elinux.org/Android_aapt
>
> (This will also dump the resource table.)