# Is there a command I can use to sign my modified apk on the command line in Linux?

Tags: android, cordova

I have an `apk` file that I built using Adobe Phonegap Build. As described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18095878/184108), I have to modify the `apk` generated by Adobe Phonegap Build before uploading it to the Google Developer Console.

I can successfully edit the file, repack the apk, and "zipalign" it. However, I am stuck on signing it. Instructions I have come across on the web assume either that one is using Eclipse, or that one is on Windows. I am on Linux, I don't use Eclipse, and I am at the command line.

I understand that to sign my app I need to have signing keys on hand, but beyond that I am unclear on what commands I need and what the parameters are.

I was able to get the `zipalign` command from the Android SDK and run it as a standalone at the command line. I'm hoping that there is a similar way I can run a program at the command line to sign my app.

Is there a command I can use to sign my modified apk on the command line in Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you use standard Java SE tools: `jarsigner` and `keytool`.

From [Android documentation on signing](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signapp):

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore my_application.apk alias_name
```

Remember that you should first sign and then align.