# Using Locale plugins

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like to make use of the Locale plugins available for Android in my own app (e.g. as down by Llama).

http://www.twofortyfouram.com/developer has some information about how to write a plugin, so I thought I could find out from there how to use a plugin as well.

From the [sample plugin download](http://www.twofortyfouram.com/developer/toast.zip) I found

```
public static final String ACTION_EDIT_SETTING = "com.twofortyfouram.locale.intent.action.EDIT_SETTING"; //$NON-NLS-1$
```

I have installed [SecureSettings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intangibleobject.securesettings.plugin) and used the technique described in [How to view AndroidManifest.xml from APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191762/how-to-view-androidmanifest-xml-from-apk-file) to decrypt its manifest. It contains this activity:

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:name=".Activities.TabsActivity" android:exported="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.twofortyfouram.locale.intent.action.EDIT_SETTING" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Which matches the string from the Locale docs above.

However, executing the code

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.twofortyfouram.locale.intent.action.EDIT_SETTING");
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

results in an ActivityNotFoundException.

I am sure I have installed SecureSettings correctly as it shows up from Llama.

Two questions:

- What do I need to change in order to bring up the activity?
- Is there any example out there which uses Locale plugins? All apps I found seem to be closed source?

Answer (score 0):

**Is there any example out there which uses Locale plugins? All apps I found seem to be closed source?**

Tasker and Locale have the same plugin structure so basically plugins made for Locale can be used for Tasker and vice versa. I don't have Locale installed in my phone but I do have Tasker and installed some free Locale plugins and they work in Tasker.

I saw some Locale/Tasker plugin source codes:

- [Locale Wifi Hotspot Plug-in](https://sites.google.com/site/localehotspotplugin/)
- [csipsimple-plugin](https://github.com/luklanis/csipsimple-plugin)
- [mytracks-tasker](https://github.com/sblom/mytracks-tasker)
- [android-notifier](https://code.google.com/p/android-notifier/)
- [Dash Notifier](https://github.com/umanx/DashNotifier)