# How to decode AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: java, android, encryption, encoding, decoding

I am trying to decode `AndroidManifest.xml`

I don't want to use APKTOOL or any of its related depedencies because I am trying to write a program that will execute on a machine/device without support for them.

Is there a name to the type of encoding of `AndroidManifest.xml`?

I am trying to write the program in Java, is there any supported libraries that could help?

Comment: tried apk parser? : https://github.com/xiaxiaocao/apk-parser

Comment: See: [How to view AndroidManifest.xml from APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191762/2533433) and also [How to parse the AndroidManifest.xml file inside an .apk package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097813/2533433). The latter even contains Java code to do that.

Comment: When I posted this question, I wanted to avoid APK tool, I wanted a java native solution only.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use/download any external tools

Recent versions of Android Studio have a tool to analyze and profile APKs.

In the latest version 3.1.2 (May 12, 2018): Go to **File > Profile or Debug Apk** does the job and more.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code: https://gist.github.com/seymores/2425692
It only uses the Java FrameWork and nothing else.