# Deploying Qt app to Android causes error

Tags: android, qt, qt-creator, qt5

When deploying Qt Application to Android using Qt Creator, I get this error:

> "Cannot open /AndroidManifest.xml for reading".

I'm using Qt 5.5.0.

Comment: That error is quite clear: either the file is not at the right place or the permissions are wrong. Please double check that file and the file permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read AndroidManifest.xml directly from your app.

Read this topic:
[How to view AndroidManifest.xml from APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191762/how-to-view-androidmanifest-xml-from-apk-file)

Comment: No. There's no APK generated yet. Qt has to generate APK file using this AndroidManifest.xml file, which is failing.