# XML file is showing garbage binary code

Tags: java, android, xml, apk

I have extracted XML files from .apk file but when i open XML file in either notepad++ or eclipse,notepad,word-pad , XML file shows garbage of binary number those are unreadable.

Comment: You need to decompile the apk if you want to view the file as plain text... Use a tool like [apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/)...

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191762/how-to-view-androidmanifest-xml-from-apk-file

Comment: but i have already decompiled the apk file with the help of apktool to extract xml file.i followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8eWnYqnM2O4