# My Android App is incompatible with almost all Android Devices

Tags: android, google-play, ionic-framework, apk

I'm thinking (or hoping) this is caused by something simple but I have deep-dived the Android developer docs, searched online, and have yet to find an answer.

My app was published a few months ago and everything was fine. But now, suddenly, it is incompatible with almost all major Android devices. In fact, in the entire Android ecosystem, only 318 devices support my app. Now my app isn't performing rocket science. All it does is send and receive data.

Here is the complete manifest file:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="901" android:versionName="1.0.0" package="com.strategy6.redshift" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
</manifest>
```

The app was developed using Ionic. We have downloaded the latest version of Ionic and recompiled, thinking that might automagically fix it, but it did not.

In my research, besides carrier and country restrictions, only the manifest file should have anything to do with apps being declared incompatible. Is there anything in this manifest file that is incorrect? Could anything else be causing this problem? Thank you in advance for any advice or assistance!

Comment: Take a look at the AndroidManifest.xml extracted from the apk file - instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191762/how-to-view-androidmanifest-xml-from-apk-file - ionic might be adding something there at build time.

Comment: it sounds to me like you have got an X86 only version of your app.
Go to Google Play Developer console and it should tell your the limitations on the APK.
That can happen when you add the crosswalk browser - it compiles an ARMv7 version and an X86 version, both of which you need to submit to the play store.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the minSDK and targetSDK parameters in your GRADLE files, those will be the values your project will be built against.