# Linking.canOpenURL returning false when targeting android 30 sdk on React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, linker, native

Recently switched our build targets to android 30 to add support for Android 11, now directions and call for phone are not working.

The documentation mentions deep linking natively and or the use of an npm package.
Would this be done natively? Or is the package an option?

https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking

Linking.canOpenURL is now returning false when checking if it is supported when running android 30.

```
Linking.canOpenURL(url)
.then((supported: boolean) => (supported ? Linking.openURL(url) : Alert.alert("Error", "There was an error attempting to opening the location.")))
.catch(() => Alert.alert("Error", "There was an error attempting to opening the location."));
```

Comment: Can you give us the url you are trying to open?

Comment: Is this solve? I can't even open `https://www.google.com` on android 11

Comment: For phone call, you can do as followed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68659891/8750763 For email:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66588577/action-send-mail-to-with-file-android-11

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The answer lies in a new Android security feature: [Package Visibility](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring). This works similar to iOS' `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`.

Targeting Android 11 (SDK 30) requires you to update your `AndroidManifest.xml` and include a list of applications you're querying for. E.g. here's the code I'm using to check for Google Maps navigation in my own app. It also includes permissions for HTTP and HTTPS:

```xml
<manifest package="com.example.game">
  <queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <data android:scheme="http"/>
    </intent>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <data android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <data android:scheme="geo" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <data android:scheme="google.navigation" />
    </intent>
  </queries>
  ...
</manifest>
```

For [applications matching certain criterias](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10158779) (such as Antivirus apps, file managers, or browser) you can use the `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` [permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES) to allow querying any random package similar to earlier Android versions:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
```

However, be aware that your application **will be rejected** from Google Play if you don't qualify as any of the app types listed below or uses the `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` in an unauthorized way:

> Permitted use involves apps that must discover any and all installed apps on the device, for awareness or interoperability purposes may have eligibility for the permission. Permitted use includes device search, antivirus apps, file managers, and browsers. Apps granted access to this permission must comply with the User Data policies, including the Prominent Disclosure and Consent requirements, and may not extend its use to undisclosed or invalid purposes.

See [Use of the broad package (App) visibility (QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES) permission](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10158779#zippy=%2Cpermitted-uses-of-the-query-all-packages-permission)

Comment: How about Phone app and emails?

Comment: @AnkitJayaprakash you need to figure out the URL schemes of the apps you're looking for and add them to the intent list. They should be documented for the specific apps you're looking for. For common intents check out https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.

The phone dialer, for example, uses android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" and android:scheme="tel".

Comment: anyone knows how to do this for non bare (expo) workflow?

Comment: bare applications designed not to work with configurations files and it works pure javascript base. So I don't think it's not possible with the expo thing. Probably they will do a release related to android 11 soon and then you can upgrade your expo SDK to latest one.

Comment: Please note that this change is required from SDK 30 onwards. The documentation is not clear on this point, making it seem that it is only required for Android 11

Answer (score 36):

In my case I needed to add a `android:host="*"` to the `data` tag like this:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="com.acme">
...
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>
```

For `Linking.canOpenURL(url)` to return `true` for `https://...` URLs.

Comment: This solved it for me! Thanks!

Comment: This fixed my issue on Android 12 and react-native-gifted-chat

Answer (score 8):

Take care if you decide to use

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
```

google says:

> Permitted use involves apps that must discover any and all installed apps on the device, for awareness or interoperability purposes may have eligibility for the permission. Permitted use includes device search, antivirus apps, file managers, and browsers.
> Apps granted access to this permission must comply with the User Data policies, including the Prominent Disclosure and Consent requirements, and may not extend its use to undisclosed or invalid purposes.

on [policy update from Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10158779#zippy=%2Cpermitted-uses-of-the-query-all-packages-permission)

Comment: I believe this one is better phrased as an edit to the top answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using expo you can add this (https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-mail/pull/175/files) to your manifest file by doing the next:

1. Create a new file at root folder named 'android-manifest.plugin.js' with the next code on it.

```
const { withAndroidManifest } = require("@expo/config-plugins")

module.exports = function androiManifestPlugin(config) {
  return withAndroidManifest(config, async config => {
    let androidManifest = config.modResults.manifest

    androidManifest["queries"].push({
        "intent": [{
            "action": [{
                "$": {
                    "android:name": "android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"
                }
            }],
            "data": [{
                "$": {
                    "android:mimeType": "*/*"
                }
            }]
        }]
    });

    return config;
  })
}
```

2. Add the plugin above to your expo config file `app.json`

```
{
  "expo": {
    ...,
    "plugins": [
      "./android-manifest.plugin.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

3. Rebuild by using a `eas build` or you can use classic (`expo build`) but remember it will be deprecated soon

That's it. Your apk should have the normal manifest plus the section that was mentioned in the link above. You can also use this approach to set your manifest as your wish. You can also verify that your manifest was successfully modified by using this tool ([How to view AndroidManifest.xml from APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191762/how-to-view-androidmanifest-xml-from-apk-file/4191807#4191807))

Comment: thanks, i need to try that, i still on sdk 45 and expo build, but as managed i have no other choice, for the moment i don't use canOpenURL and force openURL, and at least it show phone number in dialer

Answer (score -3):

By adding this in manifest resolved the issue

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
```

Thank you everyone for your support.

Comment: BEWARE: this only applies to certain types of apps (antivirus, browser, file manager etc.)