# Action send mail to with file Android 11

Tags: android, file, email, android-intent

i have a problem to share a ".zip" file with gmail app or otherwise email sender with Android 11.

```
Intent email_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto",mailTo, null));
email_intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Log App");
email_intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"");
email_intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".provider",new File(log)));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email_intent, getString(R.string.invia_tramite)));
```

I'm not using requestLegacy etc.. but getExternalFilesDir. With lower version of 11 it works.

Please save my day :)

Thanks

Comment: As @blackapps said, maybe you are referring to getExternalFilesDirs ?

Comment: @blackapps yes you are right, edited description ty

Answer (score 11, accepted):

solved with replacing:

```
Intent email_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email_intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

and in `<manifest> </manifest>` putting:

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Comment: If you are using React Native and you cannot get your mail sendto feature to work using most libraries, all you should need to do is add the manifest part of this. You add it above <application> - not in it!

Answer (score 5):

I found that sending email feedback always fail due to Android 11 restriction illustrated in below link:

[Package visibility in Android 11](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility)

To resolve this issue, we have to add query to mainfaist file like this:

```
<queries>
        <!-- Sending Emails   -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <data android:scheme="mailto" />
        </intent>
</queries>
```