# Linking opens URL in Android Emulator not in the device

Tags: react-native

I want to open a link in device browser:

```js
  const handlePaySubmit = async () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append(
      'api',
      '**********',
    );
    formData.append('amount', Number(String(tuitionPrice) + '0'));
    formData.append('redirect', 'https://gymtracker.ir/tuitionPayment');

    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://bitpay.ir/payment-test/gateway-send',
      data: formData,
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        if (typeof response.data === 'number' && response.data > 0) {
          const paymentUrl = `https://bitpay.ir/payment-test/gateway-${response.data}-get`;

          // Opening the URL
          Linking.canOpenURL(paymentUrl).then(urlResponse => {
            if (urlResponse) {
              Linking.openURL(paymentUrl);
            }
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

The code above works very well in Android emulator and its browser which is Chrome but when I use `assembleDebug` and make an output and test it on a device, it doesn't work.

When I edit AndroidManifest.xml in Debug folder as below, I get `> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED` error:

```xml
    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="28"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" android:exported="false" />
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent>
    </application>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linking.canOpenURL returning false when targeting android 30 sdk on React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64699801/linking-canopenurl-returning-false-when-targeting-android-30-sdk-on-react-native)

Comment: @user18309290 Let me check it out.

Comment: @user18309290 No it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After building **release** version of the app and running on the device, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the regarding Android manifest for your debug build

Does your manifest contain:

```
<manifest>
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Which one Michael? Main folder or Debug one?

Comment: Both should contain the permission

Comment: @MichaelNahl Main does, I used `npx uri-scheme` for generating but Debug one not. Let me test it and I'll inform you. Thanks

Comment: When I put the code above I get error. I edited my question and put the error and AndroidManifest.xml file. I was wondering if you can check it. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the snippet. checkout docs here https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking

Comment: I should replace the snippet above with Manifest file in Debug folder?

Comment: You should add the part with <queries>

Comment: I put `<queries>` tag in `<application>` tag but it throws me `Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED` error.

Comment: Even I put in `<manifest>` tag, it's OK but not working in device.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255302/discussion-between-michael-bahl-and-ali-bahaari).