# Is android app by default support both orientation?

Tags: android

I'm not developer. I'm wondering when design an android app, by default, is both orientation portrait and landscape supported?

Only when specifically required, then developer can set it locked to portrait mode only.

The reason I'm asking this, developer request to have such statement mentioned in the spec.

As a analyst, I supposed if not mentioned specifically, then the app just follow device setting.

When device is set to auto rotate, then app rotate as it.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "support". By default, if you rotate the device, then the current Activity will be recreated and shown in the new orientation. If the Activity holds state that the programmer hasn't ensured will survive the recreation, you might end up with some buggy behavior. Then there's layout, which may end up looking bad or not even fitting on screen if it has been designed with only one orientation in mind.

Comment: Any method or I can Logcat to check if developer set it only fixed portrait mode? I don't have codes, just need to be sure that developer set it.

Comment: You should be able to see that by looking at the manifest and see if `screenOrientation` is specified for any of the activities. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191762/how-to-view-androidmanifest-xml-from-apk-file) for info on how to view the manifest of an APK.

Comment: Oh I don't have the apk file. App is installed at work profile. I tried and couldn't pull it out from storage.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you do expect the developer to support both orientations it will (in many cases) involve a fair amount of additional work in creating and maintaining layout files that are optimised for both.

Comment: Yip it's by right. It should supporting both as we don't mention to cuztomize it. Except this page. The rest of pages are working in both orientation.