# Google Play rejected my update because it says I collect installed apps on device, but I don't collect such type data?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I don't collect installed apps from a device, but I use variety of libraries. I think it is probably from one of the libraries I use, If so, how can I find the library that collects such data.

Comment: Check the dependency tree via Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

The cause is most likely from the library you used. Here is the steps to find out which library collects installed apps on device. This applies if you developed the application via Java/Kotlin.

1. Decompile the application - You can use: http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk
2. Search the specific code for collecting installed apps on device one by one from the whole decompiled folder. Like `getInstalledApplications`, `getInstalledPackages`, `ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM`, for more info [How to get a list of installed android applications and pick one to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run). You can use Visual Studio Code to search specific text from a whole folder.
3. You can now find the library that you uses the code.

Comment: Did it work? Which library was the culprit?

Comment: Yes, it worked. It was appmetrica yandex analytics library. You also might want to check Facebook library if you used it.