# Finding a folder when Decompiling an APK

Tags: directory

So when you install an app and open it, it will create a folder in the internal storage of phone.  Like I installed a PSP emulator on my tablet and it made a folder PSP for saved data, cheats etc.   I decompiled the APK but I can't find the location of this mystery folder.  I searched "PSP" but nothing came up.

I decompiled the APK and searched but couldn't find the file so I could change the name.

Comment: The APK is basically a zip of app code and resources. The folder it creates is not inside the APK, inside the APK is only the code that says "create this folder pls".

Comment: But I should be able to change the name of the folder it's creating right?  That is what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: So you want it to be called not "PSP" but something else?

Comment: It might not be in the apk. It might use its own name/publisher (from APK metadata), or part of it, to determine what the folder is called. (Like if your app is called MyApp, it created a "MyApp" folder). And then it's probably not even the apk creating it - it might just be calling the OS to ask it for a folder (see https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific) (sorry, found better link)

Comment: The app I have is PPSSPP it's a PSP emulator.  It creates a folder called psp I was just trying to rename it.  I checked strings and booleans and was unsuccessful at locating the command that says make this folder

Comment: I am saying it might not be making the folder by saying "make a folder that is named PSP", it might just be calling Android system and saying "give me a folder I can store my stuff in", and Android decides what the folder is called.

Comment: Try looking for something that is inside that folder instead, like if you have PSP/someFolder/, search for someFolder in the code and check how it's constructing the path. Also, why would you check the booleans for a folder path?:)

Comment: I wasn't thinking wen I first said it lol

Comment: Where does one look normally for this code.  And your right I couldn't find it in the APK at all.  Means the same system said creat this folder.  Now I want to know how and why and how I can tell the system to make the name XXX INSTEAD of PSP when I change the name it can't find the folder.

Comment: I opened the folder and searched the APK for all the sub folder names and couldn't find anything meaning u were right the system said creat this folder

Comment: Hmm the fact that you coudn't find the subfolders either is a bit surprising. Just to make sure - by "searched the apk" you mean - you have some (probably Java) code, maybe with gibberish variable names, and you ran "search all" on the whole codebase? Anyway, for the folder name: if it's Android-created, it usually uses some property of the app to figure out the folder. Is there a maybe a "PSP" string in the APK metadata? like an application id or publisher name? I think it might be in manifest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191762/how-to-view-androidmanifest-xml-from-apk-file

Comment: If it's any consolation I'm using apktool m it's very good but i wish it had a few extras lol.  I'ma try and look again. I'll dig into it tonight.  But I looked everywhere or so I thought. . Unless there is a better APK decompiler out there.

Comment: The problem is knowing where to look